# Pyinstaller can't find own module from subfolder

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I try to create an exe file from my program.py file but can't get it to work. Right now my code structure (file structure in Explorer) is something like this:

*path_to_program / my_program / src / all_relevant_py_files_here (e.g. program.py)*

In most of the files in the src folder I do imports to other files in that folder by `import src.my_module`.

In the command prompt I have tried to run e.g. `pyinstaller -F program.py`. All works fine until I try to run the exe which gives me the error: No module named src.

I tried to run the pyinstaller from the src folder in the command prompt but this gave me a FileNotFound Error when running the exe file.

What is the way to create an exe file in Python? It seems different each time I do this depending on project structure and it is very frustrating. Is there a best way to do this that actually works each time?

Comment: How did you fix that problem?